# Question about differential equations $\tfrac {dx}{dt} = Ax$, where $x$ is a vector and $A$ is a 2x2 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

For a differential equation of this form that has complex eigenvalues, can you choose either eigenvector to set up the general solution $$x(t) = e^{pt}\,S\,(\text{rotation matrix})\,S^{-1}\,x(0)\; ?$$ I got a different answer when I set up my $S$ matrix using the negative complex conjugate eigenvalue's eigenvector. I think it changed the spiral trajectory from going counterclockwise to clockwise?

I'm just confused because our teacher said you only need to use one of the eigenvectors to set up the solution, but it seems like you get different answers depending on which one you use.

This is what my textbook states:
[image: This is what my textbook states]

Comment: Assuming that $A$ is real, the information given by one eigenvector is sufficient, but it can never be $x(0)$ because the initial condition must have real coordinates. You need to do something using the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvector.

Comment: No, the solution cannot depend on what method you use to obtain it, so you must have made some mistake. (Impossible to say what without seeing the calculations.)

Comment: @HansLundmark The problem in question is where A = (top row: -1.5, -1 bottom row: 2, 0.5). My eigenvalues were -1/2 + i and -1/2 - i. All my sin terms had opposite signs when I took different approaches. I can't find what I did wrong though.

Comment: Taking the other eigenvalue is the same thing as taking the complex conjugate of everything (or changing the signs of $q$ and $w$). Maybe that can help you track down the error?

Comment: Ah I found it. The sin terms ended up with the wrong sign with the negative complex conjugate because I didn't substitute -1 for q inside sin(qt). After doing that, it was consistent. Thanks for your help!